# Csvsimple \csvautotabular and \csvautobooktabular with centered columns' content

Tags: tables, csvsimple

I'm using *csvsimple* for making tables, and *csvautotabular* and *csvautobooktabular* are working great. However, I'd like the content of **each column** to be centered instead of aligned to the left.

An answer using *csvautotabular* and/or *csvautobooktabular* simply adding an option would be preferred, if it's possible.

I tried this, but it returns an error.

```
\csvautotabular[tabular=c]{grade.csv}

\csvautobooktabular[tabular=c]{grade.csv}
```

Here's a **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{csvsimple} % For csv importing.

% csv file from another question
\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabular{grade.csv}
\end{document}
```

And the MWE output.

[image]

I want to obtain said output, but with the content of each column centered.

---

### Note

*csvautotabular* gave me trouble trying to display special characters, but can be solved using the 'respect all' option.

e.g.

```
\csvautotabular[respect all]{table.csv}
```

Or with @egreg's custom command.

```
\csvautotabularcenter[respect all]{table.csv}
```

Comment: Don't change a question this way. The update has apparently very little to do with the rest of the question; ask a new one with the relevant example.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought this way would be better. I finally figured it out, and feel kinda silly. Edited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, there's no provision for changing the column alignment in `\csvautotabular`; you can generate a different command by mimicking what `csvsimple` does for the stock command:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{csvsimple} % For csv importing.

\makeatletter
\csvset{
  autotabularcenter/.style={
    file=#1,
    after head=\csv@pretable\begin{tabular}{|*{\csv@columncount}{c|}}\csv@tablehead,
    table head=\hline\csvlinetotablerow\\\hline,
    late after line=\\,
    table foot=\\\hline,
    late after last line=\csv@tablefoot\end{tabular}\csv@posttable,
    command=\csvlinetotablerow},
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\csvautotabularcenter}[2][]{\csvloop{autotabularcenter={#2},#1}}

% csv file from another question
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvautotabularcenter{\jobname.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A version with `\csvautobooktabularcenter`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\usepackage{csvsimple} % For csv importing.

\makeatletter
\csvset{
  autotabularcenter/.style={
    file=#1,
    after head=\csv@pretable\begin{tabular}{|*{\csv@columncount}{c|}}\csv@tablehead,
    table head=\hline\csvlinetotablerow\\\hline,
    late after line=\\,
    table foot=\\\hline,
    late after last line=\csv@tablefoot\end{tabular}\csv@posttable,
    command=\csvlinetotablerow},
  autobooktabularcenter/.style={
    file=#1,
    after head=\csv@pretable\begin{tabular}{*{\csv@columncount}{c}}\csv@tablehead,
    table head=\toprule\csvlinetotablerow\\\midrule,
    late after line=\\,
    table foot=\\\bottomrule,
    late after last line=\csv@tablefoot\end{tabular}\csv@posttable,
    command=\csvlinetotablerow},
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\csvautotabularcenter}[2][]{\csvloop{autotabularcenter={#2},#1}}
\newcommand{\csvautobooktabularcenter}[2][]{\csvloop{autobooktabularcenter={#2},#1}}

% csv file from another question
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvautotabularcenter{\jobname.csv}

\bigskip

\csvautobooktabularcenter{\jobname.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked beautifully! Would it be too much to ask to have also the *\csvautobooktabular* version of the custom command?

Comment: @CalculusKnight You're welcome!

Comment: Any clue on how to add the 'respect all' option to the custom command? I tried to figure it out on my own but, to my eyes, it's wizardry.

Comment: @CalculusKnight Sorry, but I don't know what you're talking about. You probably are an expert with `csvsimple`; I just read the necessary code and modified it.

Answer (score 2):

I found [the manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf) almost incomprehensible for the most part. But it mentions several times that you typically wouldn't use `\csvautotabular` or `\csvautobooktabular` in practice.

They suggest using `\csvreader`. Here is a minimal use case of `\csvreader`, which may be preferable for other people (as it was for me).

```latex
\csvreader[
  tabular=|c|c|r|c|r|,
  table head=\hline \bfseries{Name} & \bfseries{Given Name} & \bfseries{Matriculation} & \bfseries{Gender} & \bfseries{Grade} \\\hline,
  late after last line=\\\hline % horizontal line at the end of the table
]{
  grade.csv
}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}
```

[image: Table with various alignments]

Pros vs egreg's solution:

- More control over table header and column alignments
- Less overall code for a single table

Cons vs egreg's solution:

- More overall code if you're going to use it for many tables

Comment: And how to center all columns without writing out explicitly the string for `tabular` when one, for example, doesn't know how many columns there are or if the number of in the input csv file can change.? Thank you

Comment: If you want that, then use egreg's solution. However, if you want number columns to be right-aligned and the rest centred - as I've shown here - then that won't work (which is why I posted this answer). The only way I know how to include different alignments is to do it is explicitly. PS. I'm not a TeXpert, so there may be a way, but I don't know it.