# Add vertical line to csv simple table

Tags: tables, csvsimple

I cannot figure out how to modify the Code given in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292512/csvsimple-csvautotabular-and-csvautobooktabular-with-centered-columns-content)
in order to create an horizontal line over the last entry of the last column. That means I want the table to look like this (please excuse my bad drawing ;)):

[image]

Thank you

Comment: While it might be possible to hack something in that direction, I am not sure whether CSV is actually the right tool to accomplish this. CSV has merely a definition of a "header" row. Maybe using one of the tabular* packages is the easier way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
late after line=\ifnumequal{\thecsvrow}{3}{\\\midrule}{\\},
```

too add a rule at a certain line.

The full source code is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,booktabs}

% csv file
\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[
  tabular=ccccc,
  table head=\toprule name & givenname & matriculation & gender & grade\\\midrule,
  late after line=\ifnumequal{\thecsvrow}{3}{\\\midrule}{\\},
  late after last line=\\,
  table foot=\bottomrule,
  head to column names,
  ]
  {grade.csv}{}
  {\name & \givenname & \matriculation & \gender & \grade}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**

To use a dashed line, the `arydshln` package may be used which provides `\hdashline`. I have no experience with that package, but the following seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,booktabs,arydshln}

% csv file
\begin{filecontents*}{grade.csv}
name,givenname,matriculation,gender,grade
Maier,Hans,12345,m,1.0
Huber,Anna,23456,f,2.3
Weisbaeck,Werner,34567,m,5.0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[
  tabular=ccccc,
  table head=\toprule name & givenname & matriculation & gender & grade\\\midrule,
  late after line=\ifnumequal{\thecsvrow}{3}{\\\hdashline}{\\},
  late after last line=\\,
  table foot=\bottomrule,
  head to column names,
  ]
  {grade.csv}{}
  {\name & \givenname & \matriculation & \gender & \grade}
\end{document}
```

This gives:
[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much. Do you maybe even know if there is a way to make this new line appear in a dashed style?

Comment: @s88_py I updated my answer with some code for a dashed style.